# How to test if a type parameter is a template type

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a template class like so:

```
template < typename TParam >
class Test
{
// content
};
```

I want to pull out the first template parameter of `TParam` if it's a specialization of a class template. Something like:

```
template < typename TParam >
class Test
{
    using TParamInner = TemplateType<TParam>::Type;
    // use TParamInner here
};
```

Additional info:

- I have access to all of C++98.
- I have access to a subset of C++11.
- I would prefer to avoid the stdlib if possible (assume this is
  because I'm using an embedded system for which no stdlib is available and/or because I am heavily memory-constrained)

Comment: You can't. You can have a specialization of your `Test` for a **known** templates, but you can't have a generic test to check if your argument is *any** template.

Comment: afaik once TParam gets passed as parameter to your template, it could only be the instantiation of a template but not a template anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get close with something like:

```
template <class >
struct first_template_param;

template <template <class...> class Z, class T, class... Ts>
struct first_template_param<Z<T, Ts...>> {
    using type = T;
}
```

It won't handle `std::array` or any other class templates that take non-type template parameters. But it'll handle all the "normal" class templates. You can always then add extra specializations for all the ones you want:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
struct first_template_param<std::array<T,N>> {
    using type = T;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the first part of your answer I've discovered the full solution. I can either propose it as an edit to this answer (so you get full credit) or create a new answer and cite your answer as the thing that spurred my rcognitive leap. Do you have a preference?

Comment: @Pharap I don't think there is a full solution, I can always come up with some weird template that takes some bizarre collection of non-type parameters. But definitely create a new answer - editing is for fixing minor issues, not altering the answer.

Comment: It's not a full solution for templates that accept integrals such as int as parameters, but it's a solution for accessing the types of templates where the template parameters are all types.

Comment: @Pharap Oh, well that's just a matter of adding support for that. That wasn't part of your question.

Comment: @Pharap I edited your question to make it clear that what you want is the first type, and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barry for spurring the solution along.

It's not a complete answer for all template types, but it works for templates where all parameters are types, which is a large number of the most useful templates.

```
template < typename Head, typename ... Tail >
struct split { using first = Head; };

template <class >
struct cls_template_info; // fails on non-templates

template <template <class...> class Z, class... Ts>
struct cls_template_info<Z<Ts...>>
{
using type = typename split<Ts...>::first; // typename used to disambiguate
};
```

This can then be used as `using T = cls_template_info<std::vector<int>>::first;`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't.  A template type *is never carried up to runtime*.  You have to instantiate it (this leads to a complete new type), and the compiler then generates the needed code to make it appear as if you have defined specifically for the type parameters you specified. Indeed, in old compilers (this has been solved a lot of time ago) when you instantiate a generic type in several compilation units, that lead to several repetitions of the same code in the final program.  But as I've said, this has been solved time ago.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Barry's solution was precisely the solution I was looking for, being able to ensure a template parameter was itself a template class and being able to extract that class' template parameters at compile time. I know full well how templates work and I didn't say anything about runtime.